# Chatbot web plugin - A web alternative to Facebook messenger and friends

Tags: chat, bots, chatbot, facebook-chatbot, skype-bots

I'm looking for a way to simulate our chatbots on a web page and not inside Facebook Messenger / Slack / Telegram etc...

Does any one knows of such project?

- Someone needs to open an open-source project for a chatbots browser.

Answer (score 1):

[socket.io](https://socket.io/demos/chat/) is a great platform to start building this functionality on.